# extracting member variables from struct or class

Tags: c++, c, class, struct

Is there a tool that can extract the member variables from a given struct or class from the source code?
What I'm expecting is the following

Let's say target.c is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct A {
    int a;
    int b;
};
int main()
{
    blah...
}
```

And, if I do something like in bash:

```
$ extract-member target.c A
struct A member list:
 - int a;
 - int b;
```

is there a tool like 'extract-member'?

Comment: I'm not familiar with any tool like that, but to create one is not too hard. All you need to do is find certain keyword within a file, say "class" key word, then extract the member within it.

Comment: @lightbringer: it's legendarily hard to do well, due to the potential use of includes, preprocessor macros, comments, trigraphs, legal C++ code that can only be interpreted accurately with knowledge of the prior declarations - generally, the extraordinary complexity of C++...

Comment: The thing is in side struct, there could be comments. So, I think some kind of reg-ex is required there.

Comment: What is this good for anyway...

Comment: @Havenard: I'm thinking to make a simple tool that visualize the call trace and it's corresponding structures

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Programs like ctags, doxygen, gccxml all offer approaches to this... you might want to read about them online and decide which suits your needs.

Comment: as far as I know, ctags and doxygen do not have API exposed to access those kind of internal structures. I expect I can read the source of ctags and doxygen for that purpose, but I'm finding a easier way, if there is any. And, I'm new to gccxml, maybe I have to look it up.

Comment: From the gccxml introduction, looks like it fits the purpose of mine. Thanks!

Comment: @jaeyong: for doxygen, I think it's the GENERATE_XML option - you may be right that there's no API, but you can load the output using whatever XML library's API you like.  ctags may be harder for you to use as I suspect you're right that there's no convenient standard API, as far as I know apps using ctags output write their own parsing code.